# Excel NETWORKDAYS - Do these returned values look more reasonable?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Do these returned values look more reasonable for NETWORKDAYS?

2013/6/26 Wed
2013/6/27 Thu
2013/6/28 Fri

```
=NETWORKDAYS("2013/6/27","2013/6/26") = -2
```

Should above better return -1?

```
=NETWORKDAYS("2013/6/27","2013/6/27") = 1
```

Should above better return 0?

```
=NETWORKDAYS("2013/6/27","2013/6/28") = 2
```

Should above better return 1?

Comment: I think you could use an `IF()` formula on top of the `NETWORKDAYS()` to get the values you are expecting, such as `=if(NETWORKDAYS("2013/6/27","2013/6/26")<0,NETWORKDAYS("2013/6/27","2013/6/26")+1,NETWORKDAYS("2013/6/27","2013/6/26")-1)`.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I come up with the same too.

Comment: NETWORKDAYS always includes both start and end date, if you don't want that you can use `=NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)-SIGN(NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2))`

Comment: Thanks Barry for the neater solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you worked on the 27th, you'd say your start day is the 27th, your end day is 27th, and net days is 1.

Seems perfectly valid for me.

Comment: Thanks GregHNZ, I see what you mean.  Maybe NETWORKDAYS is not for the opposite and I will need to accept that.